# Is Docker an emulator? If not, why not?

Tags: docker, terminology

Is Docker an emulator? If not, why not?

It emulates an operating system in a certain **state/mode**, isn't it?

Comment: please read [Docker overview](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/)

Comment: Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is a container system.   It separates the operating system into a host operating system and multiple pieces that run isolated pieces of possible other operating systems or the same operating system.

If it was an emulator, it would be pretending to be something else,like emulating one cpu when it is really a different cpu, or pretending to be some other hardware which it isn't.

If it was emulating an operating system, you would be running a fake operating system rather than a real one.

It is neither of those.  Docker runs real operating systems (in pieces) on real hardware, and is generally faster than an emulator.  (And will be faster on the same hardware.)